# Relative de Rahm cohomology computation for two disjoint circles embedded in $\mathbb{R}^2$

Tags: differential-geometry, algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

Consider a submanifold $Y$ of $\mathbb{R}^2$ formed by two disjoint embedded copies of $S^1.$ Compute $H^{\bullet}_{dR}(\mathbb{R}^2,Y).$

In this case the long exact sequence splits, and we can easily see that $H^2_{dR}(\mathbb{R}^2,Y)=\mathbb{R}^2;$ from the properties of relative cohomology and the fact that $\mathbb{R}^2$ is connected, I get $H^0_{dR}(\mathbb{R}^2,Y)=0,$
and this is a bit strange, and finally I don't know how to compute $H^1_{dR}(\mathbb{R}^2,Y).$ The exact sequence I was mentioning is
$$ 0 \to H^0_{dR}(\mathbb{R}^2,Y) \to \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}^2 \to H^1_{dR}(\mathbb{R}^2,Y) \to 0.$$

Comment: Can you see what the map $\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}^2$ is going to be? Hint, consider the sum of two generators of $H^0_{dR}(S^1_a)$ and $H^0_{dR}(S^1_b)$. From this, can you find the kernel and image?

Comment: if $H^0_{dR}(\mathbb{R}^2,Y)=0,$ then the map is injective, but more than this I don't see; for me it comes from the connecting morphism in a long exact sequence

Comment: Remember, the homomorphism $\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}^2$ is induced by an inclusion map $S^1\sqcup S^1\to \mathbb{R}^2$. On the $H^0_{dR}$ level this map is particularly easy to define in terms of path components. Go back to the definition of this induced map in order to get an explicit induced homomorphism.